# Storing birthday in database, what type to use if there's missing values

Tags: mysql, r, date

I am collecting sports data for a database I will be creating soon, and one of the columns I have for one of my tables is player birthdays. I am using R to scrape and collect the data, and here is what it currently looks like:

```
head(my_df)

        Name        BirthDate     Age                 Place  Height  Weight
1       Mike                       NA                            NA      NA
2     Austin  August 17, 1994  22.295 Roseville, California      73     210
3       Koby January 19, 1997  20.140      Wolfforth, Texas      70     255
4         Ty             1991  26.000       Amarillo, Texas      70     165
5       Cole                       NA                            NA      NA
6       Jeff    July 24, 1995  21.320     Boulder, Colorado      72     200

dput(head(my_df))
structure(list(Name = c("Mike", "Austin", "Koby", "Ty", "Cole", 
"Jeff"), BirthDate = c("", "August 17, 1994", "January 19, 1997", 
"1991", "", "July 24, 1995"), Age = c(NA, 22.295, 20.14, 26, 
NA, 21.32), Place = c("", "Roseville, California", "Wolfforth, Texas", 
"Amarillo, Texas", "", "Boulder, Colorado"), Height = c(NA, 73, 
70, 70, NA, 72), Weight = c(NA, 210L, 255L, 165L, NA, 200L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"BirthDate", "Age", "Place", "Height", "Weight"), row.names = 25:30, class = "data.frame")
```

The `BirthDate` column has two inconsistencies that make appropriate formatting difficult:

1. there are entirely missing values
2. for some columns, I have the birthyear but am missing Day and Month.

I'm relatively new with databases and am trying to plan ahead with this. Does anybody have any thoughts on the best way to handle this? To be more specific, how can I write the R code to format the column the right way?

Comment: I would separate BirthDate into 3 columns, Year, Day, Month. And fill in missings with either 1st Jan, or 15th Jun. Then put them back together to have a valid date.

Comment: Missing altogether is easy. That's just NULL.

Comment: 3 columns is what I was leaning towards

Comment: however if i did 3 columns, isn't it better to do NA for missing day and month, not 1st Jan or 15th Jun?

Comment: If you are not planning to use the dates for calculations, then keep as string in one column. The reason to add 1stJan or 15thJun, is to convert them to date class, so that we can use them for calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but a direction to try...
Genealogy databases, which have similar problems, will often have an extra column (a sort of meta-date column) that expresses confidence in, or quality of, the birth-date column. This can then be used at query-time to mediate the results returned. Could be "estimated", "not given", "year only" to suit your app.

Comment: estimated is interesting way to think about it, but i don't have uncertainty in the data, just missing values

Comment: .SQL date format will let you put 00 in months and/or days: 1920-00-00. I am just saying it is good practice to record why such data is in the database, at data-entry time when you know what is happening. It is a pain later to have to infer at query time the the 00 is not an error but is data awaiting being entered. Perhaps "estimated" would not be one of your quality indicators but "year only", "year month only" might be.  Would support data-cleaning maintenance queries to generate e.g. e-mails to elicit full birth-date, at some later date.

Comment: okay makes sense, yeah having a meta-date column with the indicators you mentioned makes a lot of sense actually

Answer (score 0):

If we intend to do calculations on date as date, or on year and month columns, for example: the age of the player, how many of them were born on January, etc. then we can can separate it into 3 numeric columns.

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(my_df$BirthDate, function(i){
          x <- rev(unlist(strsplit(i, " ")))
          res <- data.frame(
            BirthDate = i,
            YYYY = as.numeric(x[1]),
            DD = as.numeric(sub(",", "", x[2], fixed = TRUE)),
            MM = match(x[3], month.name))
          res$DOB <- as.Date(paste(res$DD, res$MM, res$YYYY, sep = "/"),
                             format = "%d/%m/%Y")
          res
        }))

#          BirthDate YYYY DD MM        DOB
# 1                    NA NA NA       <NA>
# 2  August 17, 1994 1994 17  8 1994-08-17
# 3 January 19, 1997 1997 19  1 1997-01-19
# 4             1991 1991 NA NA       <NA>
# 5                    NA NA NA       <NA>
# 6    July 24, 1995 1995 24  7 1995-07-24
```